# How to combine two separate IQueryable<string> collections into one?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 separate collections.

```
IQueryable<string> customers;
IQueryable<string> customersPhone
```

Currently, this is the code I am using to join one with the other

```
IEnumerable<string> union = customers.Union(customersPhone);
```

The problem is that when I have multiple like records in the customers collection, the union is causing only a single record to be returned.  I need to return all, regardless of duplicates, and join them with the customersPhone collection.

Is this possible?  Does that make sense?

Thanks!
Kevin

Comment: Union is a set operation; sets by definition exclude duplicates.  As SLaks says, you should use `Concat()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `Concat()`, which preserves duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you could try one of the 2 options below List one is customers in your case list2 would be customerPhone make the corrections to fit your Use Case

IQueryable customers;
IQueryable customersPhone

```
var list1 = list1.Concat(customers);
```

or

```
var list4 = list1.Union(customersPhone);
```